# Misreported Account Kit data in Facebook Analytics

Tags: facebook-analytics, account-kit

I logged in ~1500 people via Account Kit (basic web) in the last 12 hours.

However, in Facebook Analytics, the Account Kit funnel shows 2.65% conversion, with 754 people at the starting point, and 20 people at the end.

Whichever way I slice or dice it, this is inaccurate reporting.

This Account Kit funnel was auto-generated for me. I don't seem to have control over editing it in Facebook-Analytics. For starters, I can't even tell whether this reporting error emanates from Account Kit, or from Facebook Analytics.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just wanted to check with you and see if you're still having this issue?

Things should be working fine from the AccountKit side now, but if you're still having an issue please submit a request with your app id on: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/